# vtip jQuery to display titles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using vTip plugin to display titles on hover , here is my example code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/

I have a Div#showTitles , When i click on it I wants to toggle display of all div.vtips titles on page just like mouseover.

```
$("#showTitles").click(function(){
  // this I am not sure how to acheive.  
  return false;
});
```

**UPDATE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/2/
I have tried this but its not showing on correct positions as mouseover but once i mouseover on .vtip and then i click on #showTitles its working fine, I also need to toggle this behavior :

```
$("#showTitles").click(function(e,ui){

this.xOffset = 5; 
this.yOffset = 10; 
this.top = (e.pageY + yOffset); 
this.left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

  $('.vtip').each(function(index) {
    title = $(this).text();
    $('body').append( '<p id="vtip"><img id="vtipArrow" />' + title + '</p>' );

        $('p#vtip #vtipArrow').attr("src", 'images/vtip_arrow.png');
        $('p#vtip').css("top", this.top+"px").css("left",  
   this.left+"px").fadeIn("slow");

 });
   return false;
 });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs should be unique.<sup>*finished*</sup>
I've modified your current code to get it work under the current conditions. The function logic should be obvious because of the descriptive names. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/7/**

Update: Added show/hide text + feature to the code, as requested at the comments.
Update2: Taken care of whole code, improved efficiency.

You're overusing `this`. `this.xOffset = 5` attaches `xOffset` to the element. Use `var xOffset = 5` to define `xOffset` in the scope of the function. The code below has the following scope model:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Variables defined using `var` can be read by
   //   any function defined within this function
   function vtip(){
      // variables declared here can be read by any function defined inside vtip
      // but cannot be read by methods outside vtip
      function(){..} at .hover and .mousemove
         // These functions also have an own scope, and variables defined using
         // var cannot be read by anything outside these functions, even at vtip
   $("#showTitles").click(function(e){
      // variables declared here cannot be read by code outside this function
      // This function can read any variable which is declared using var at
      // $(document).ready
```

Note: "Declare" means "Define using `var`".

Final code:

```
// Run when the DOM is ready
//Note: $(function(){ is short for  $(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    var xOffset = 5; // x distance from mouse
    var yOffset = 10; // y distance from mouse
    var frozen_vtip = false; //Define it
    var vtip = function() {    

        $(".displaytip").unbind().hover(    
            function(e) {
                if(frozen_vtip) return;
                this.t = this.title;
                this.title = '';
                var top = (e.pageY + yOffset);
                var left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

                $('<p class="vtip"><img class="vtipArrow" src=""/>' + this.t + '</p>').css("top", top+"px").css("left", left+"px").fadeIn("slow").appendTo(this);

            },
            function() {
                if(frozen_vtip) return;
                this.title = this.t;
                $("p.vtip", this).fadeOut("slow").remove();
            }
        ).mousemove(
            function(e) {
                if(frozen_vtip) return;
                var top = (e.pageY + yOffset);
                var left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

                $("p.vtip", this).css("top", top+"px").css("left", left+"px");
            }
        );  
    };
    vtip();


// Second function, when text is "Hide titles" it should
// prevent runing vtip() on mouseover (above function) and
// when text is  "Show titles" It should normally run vtip()
// (mouseover display title.

    $("#showTitles").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).text() == "Hide titles"){
            $(this).text("Show titles");
            $('p.vtip').fadeOut("slow").remove();
            $('.displaytip').each(function(){
                this.title = this.t; //Re-attach `title`
            });
            frozen_vtip = false;
        } else {
            frozen_vtip = true;
            $(this).text("Hide titles");
            $('.displaytip').each(function(index) {
                if($('p.vtip', this).length) {return;}
                this.t = this.title;
                this.title = '';   
                var $this = $(this);
                var offset = $this.offset();
                var height = $this.height();
                var top = offset.top + height;
                var left = offset.left + height;
                $('<p class="vtip"><img class="vtipArrow" src="images/vtip_arrow.png" />' + this.t + '</p>' ).appendTo(this).css("top", top+"px").css("left", left+"px").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir I have changed it to class http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/4/  is that possible to toggle this behavior so when i click #showTitles it will display titles as are now and disable vtip() so on mouseover all titles should be visible and #showTitles inner text become "Hide Titles" and when i click hide titles it will again enable vtip() functionality. Regards

Comment: Thanks again sir but actually one thing is still missing from my request. what I need is when it display all titles by clicking on "Show titles" and later when I move mouse to any element, none of title should hide they should stick until i dont click "Hide titles" and then go back to mouseover function to display that title. here I have changed it to 2 separate functions if that make sense. http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/6/  thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Dshah I have checked your whole code. It's now more efficient and reliable.

Comment: that looks good sir and thanks for explanation , appreciate for your help, but any idea why its not working in chrome/IE? only works in firefox

Comment: Found it was issue in css (p.vtip display: none; ) had to remove from CSS . http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/9/ updated code :) Thanks for your help

Comment: hi again a small issue in this please see this http://screensnapr.com/v/sZDzIp.png  , please click twice here on show  http://jsfiddle.net/bnjSs/10/ it works fine on first click but on second it delete title. I added this this.t = this.title;
                this.title = '';      see my comment please at the end.

Comment: @Dshah You also had to set `this.title = this.t` in a loop at `if($(this).text() == "Hide titles"){`.

Comment: Thanks a lot all on place now :) Best Regards